# R: Shiny.OnInputChange live click

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

Say I have an object in the browser DOM with `class=“row”` and `id=“row22”`.

I want to use `Shiny.onInputChange()` to detect a click on that object and send the id to a Shiny `input$` variable. I’ve worn out Google looking for an example of how to do this but haven’t come up with anything. Could someone who knows how to do this provide some sample code?
it should work something like `$(document).on` in jquery

For example:

In Javascript, added a function that looks like this:

```
function my_row(n) {
  Shiny.onInputChange("js.row", n);
};
```

In Shiny code added an observer that looks for changes on 
      `input$js.row`  :

```
 observeEvent(input$js.row, {
    print(paste0("Value of js.row is ", input$js.row))
 })
```

still `Shiny.OnInputChange` not triggering `observeEvent(input$js.row`! Do we have alternative approach?

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: No, I have taken different approach, which I cant place here

Comment: changing the button id dynamically

Comment: Glad to hear you found a way! It would be at least nice if you rate the given answer. Is it a good answer(upvote) and does it answer the described challenge in the question (accept answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code snippets look like a good starting Point.

Without knowing the full could i think you have to add some Code when you trigget the action with:

```
function my_row(n) {
  Shiny.onInputChange("js.row", n);
};
```

As you want to trigger the function, when the element with id = row22 you can use:

```
document.getElementById('row22').onclick
```

But you have to wait until shiny is loaded. That can be done with:

```
$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
```

Full example would read:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("
    $(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) { // wait for shiny to be loaded
      document.getElementById('row22').onclick = function(elem) {
        Shiny.onInputChange('jsrow', elem.srcElement.textContent);
      };
    });
  "),

  div(class = "row", id = "row21", "counter example"), 
  div(class = "row", id = "row22", "target: click me!") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$jsrow, {
    print(paste0("Value of js.row is ", input$jsrow))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```